# Selenium cannot find element: directly under div

Tags: selenium, automated-tests

I am trying to use xpath to find a specific text from a page. Selenium can not find this exact text.

Here is the code I am trying with:

```
searchresult = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Sorry, we could not find the book you were looking for.')]")
```

Here is the HTML I am working on:

```
<div style="width:100%;padding: 20px;">
    <div class="searchbox">
    </div>
    <div class="vert-spacing-15"></div>

    Sorry, we could not find the book you were looking for. Please try 
    searching for something else.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like:

```
//*[contains(., 'Sorry, we could not find the book you were looking for.')]
```

Why? Because text() will only match the text before the first child element.

Comment: thanks. it does work for this scenario but weirdly it returns the element even when it is not actually present in the HTML. any idea ?

Comment: check if the `display` attribute is controlling the element on GUI. Just check in devtools by entering the text in Elements tab, so that you will get to know from where it's pulling the element though you don't see it.

Comment: thank you. Found the reason. It was an error from my end. Thanks a lot for explaining :)